# Computation of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Consider the following integral:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x e^{-\left(2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right) x^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y + a x)^2}} dy dx}$$

I was able to integrate over $y$ to get:

$$ I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty}{x e^{-\left(2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right) x^2} (1-erf(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}})) dx}$$

However, I find it difficult to integrate over $x$. Is it possible to compute the above integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $b > 1/\sqrt {2}$ and using Maple I am obtaining

[image]

In order to derive the result by hand using pen and paper please write

$$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}( \int_{0}^{\infty}{x e^{-\left(2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right) x^2}dx- \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\left(2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right) x^2} erf(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}}) dx})$$

The first integral is computed directly.  The second integral is computed by parts with

$$u=erf(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}})$$

$$dv=xe^{-\left(2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right) x^2}dx$$

Comment: I think this fits better as a comment than an answer, since it does not give any hint on how to actually obtain the result (other than to buy/use maple).

Comment: Hi @mickep, you are right. Now, I am giving some hints on how to compute the integral by hand.  All the best.

Comment: Using Juan hint, I get:
$$ I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{b^2}{4b^2-2} - \frac{a b^2}{4b^2-2} \int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-(2-\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{a^2}{2})x^2} dx}$$

Comment: Performing a change of variable $t = \sqrt{2-\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}} x$ in the above integral, we get the result. Thanks Juan.

Answer (score 2):

In retrospect, this takes a lot longer than integrating in $y$ first. But anyway, by completing the square of the quadratic form in the exponential one can solve it by integrating in $x$ first. We write
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\left[ (2 + a^{2}/2 - 1/b^{2})x^{2} + ayx + y^{2}/2\right]}\,dx\,dy.
\end{equation}
Define $\gamma^{2} := 2 + \frac{a^{2}}{2}- \frac{1}{b^{2}}$, which we assume to be strictly positive. Then we write
\begin{equation}
\left(2 + \frac{a^{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)x^{2} + ayx + \frac{y^{2}}{2} = \left(\gamma x + \frac{ay}{2\gamma}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}\right)y^{2}.
\end{equation}

Now use the substitution $u = \gamma x + \frac{ay}{2\gamma}$ so that $x = \frac{u}{\gamma} - \frac{ay}{2\gamma^{2}}$. We have
\begin{align*}
I & = \frac{1}{\gamma} \int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{u=\frac{ay}{2\gamma}}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u}{\gamma} - \frac{ay}{2\gamma^{2}}\right)e^{-u^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}\right)y^{2}}\,du\,dy\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\int_{y=0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-a^{2}y^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}}e^{\frac{a^{2}y^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}}\,dy - \frac{a}{2 \gamma^{3}} \int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{u=\frac{ay}{2\gamma}}^{\infty}ye^{-u^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}\right)y^{2}}\,du\,dy\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{2 \gamma^{3}} \int_{u=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^{\frac{2\gamma u}{a}}ye^{-u^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}}\right)y^{2}}\,dy\,du
\end{align*}
Define $\beta^{2} := \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}} = \frac{2 - \frac{1}{b^{2}}}{4 + a^{2} - \frac{2}{b^{2}}}$, which is positive if $\gamma^{2}$ is. Also note the identities:
\begin{align*}
\gamma^{2}\beta^{2} & = 1 - \frac{1}{2b^{2}}\\
a^{2} + 4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2} & = 2\gamma^{2}.
\end{align*}

Make the substitution $w = \beta y$ to get
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{2 \gamma^{3}\beta^{2}} \int_{u=0}^{\infty}\int_{w=0}^{\frac{2\gamma \beta u}{a}}we^{-u^{2}}e^{-w^{2}}\,dw\,du\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\int_{u=0}^{\infty}\int_{s=0}^{\frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}u^{2}}{a^{2}}}e^{-s}\,ds\,du, \quad (s = w^{2})\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\int_{u=0}^{\infty}e^{-u^{2}}\left(1 - e^{-\frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}u^{2}}{a^{2}}}\right)\,du\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} + \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\int_{u=0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1 + \frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}{a^{2}}\right)u^{2}}\,du\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} + \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1 + \frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}{a^{2}}}}
\end{align*}

To further simplify, we proceed:
\begin{align*}
I & = \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} + \frac{a}{4\gamma^{3}\beta^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1 + \frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}{a^{2}}}}\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\gamma} - \frac{a}{8\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\gamma^{2}}} \right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\gamma}\left[1 + \frac{a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\right] - \frac{a}{8\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\gamma}\left[\frac{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2} + a^{2}}{4\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\right] - \frac{a}{8\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\gamma}\left[\frac{2\gamma^{2}}{4\left(1 - \frac{1}{2b^{2}}\right)}\right] - \frac{a}{8\left(1 - \frac{1}{2b^{2}}\right)}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}\gamma - a}{8\left(1 - \frac{1}{2b^{2}}\right)}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Note that $\sqrt{2}b\gamma = \sqrt{4b^{2} + a^{2}b^{2} - 2}$. So
\begin{align*}
I & = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{2}b}{\sqrt{2}b\gamma}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}b\gamma - ab}{8b\left(\frac{2b^{2} - 1}{2b^{2}}\right)}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{4b^{2} + a^{2}b^{2} - 2}}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{4b^{2} + a^{2}b^{2} - 2} - ab}{8\left(\frac{2b^{2} - 1}{2b^{2}}\right)}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{2}b^{2}}{\sqrt{4b^{2} + a^{2}b^{2} - 2}}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{4b^{2} + a^{2}b^{2} - 2} - ab}{4\left(2b^{2} - 1\right)}\right)\\
\end{align*}

I can't seem to locate where the extra $2$ is coming from, which is the only difference between the final equation below and what was obtained in the other contributor's solution. Obviously, this is the longer way to do this problem, and it's more prone to mistakes. So I think I'll leave it as is.